# I have an idea to use auth middleware to retrieve a user's products

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

i have an idea to use auth middleware to retrieve a user's products but currently i am not able to retrieve that user's products. Instead, it listed all the products of other users. Can you guys give me some ideas to help me complete it. Thank you !!!

[image]

This is my ProjectController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\ProjectResource;
use App\Models\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::all();

        return response([
            'projects' => ProjectResource::collection($projects),
            'message' => 'Retrieved successfully'
        ], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            // 'uuid' => 'required|unique:projects',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'status' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
        }

        $projects = Project::create($data);

        return response(['projects' => new ProjectResource($projects), 'message' => 'Created successfully'], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        return response(['project' => new ProjectResource($project), 'message' => 'Retrieved successfully'], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $project->update($request->all());

        return response(['project' => new ProjectResource($project), 'message' => 'Update successfully'], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();

        return response(['message' => 'Deleted'], 204);
    }
}
```

This is my ProjectModel code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\ProjectStatus;
use App\Http\Traits\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Uuid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'status',
        'user_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
        'uuid',
    ];

    protected $cast = [
        'status' => ProjectStatus::class
    ];

    public function setUuidAttribute()
    {
        $this->attributes['uuid'] = Str::uuid();
    }
}
```

This is my API Router code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrieve the user first in order to filter the products. There are multiple ways to do that. Here's a link to Laravel's documentation on the subject: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

You also have to filter your query (your query being `Project::all()`) so that it only retrieves the products for the user. Here's a link to some Laravel documentation related to that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

In the end, replacing this `$projects = Project::all();` with this `$projects = Project::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();

        return response([
            'projects' => ProjectResource::collection($projects),
            'message' => 'Retrieved successfully'
        ], 200);
    }
```