# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto()

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, middleware, laravel-sanctum

I get the following error when adding to the command line like this:

> error: Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto()

This is my code:
[image]

If i leave out the command line `Project::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)` go and replace it with the command line `Project::all()`
everything works fine but i want to get the list of projects belonging to a certain user then i have to use the other command this makes me almost like i can't find a way to deal with it.

Error message:
[image]

I have consulted the following post to be able to retrieve by user_id:
[I have an idea to use auth middleware to retrieve a user's products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770468/i-have-an-idea-to-use-auth-middleware-to-retrieve-a-users-products)

Comment: Have you viewed this content https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710805/laravel-api-resource-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builder

Comment: I tried this it seems it didn't work in my project. Finally, thank you for suggesting to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Eloquent model acts as a query builder, you can add additional constraints to the queries and then call the **get** method to get the results.

Other methods :

- all
- get
- first

For Laravel Eloquent => https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

I think this might be the right solution for you :

```
project::Where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine. Thank you for helping me with a useful solution